# Support different screen size at landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android application I have to show the landscape view for large and small screen sizes. Is there any method to do this . If then how can I do that? Now I have just created a 'layout-land' folder. Can I give it more specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify like this :

```
layout-land-hdpi 
layout-land-ldpi 
layout-land-mdpi 
layout-small-land-ldpi
```

and for more detail read this :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

There is also a very good lesson in android developer site :

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout-large-land` and `layout-small-land`; see also [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).