# layout-land not picking landscape layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a different layout for landscape & portrait. But both the orientations end up using the same layout xml. I've gone though more than a dozen of questions on StackOverflow but none of it solves my problem.

Under layouts I have a `activity_main.xml` file.
I have folders for different landscape layouts as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376060/317512) answer:

```
layout/  
   activity_main.xml 
   layout-land-hdpi/
      activity_main.xml
   layout-land-ldpi/ 
      activity_main.xml
   layout-land-mdpi/ 
      activity_main.xml
   layout-small-land-ldpi/
      activity_main.xml
```

These have the same `activity_main.xml` file except that the background color is different.

I do not have `android:configChanges` set in AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity. I am not overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` as I am not manually dealing with orientation changes.

I am using actionbarsherlock library in the project. I made action bar themes using [ActionBar Sytele Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

minSdk & TargetSdk from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I am running the code on Emulators running Android 4.3(Galaxy Nexus), Android 4.2.2(Nexus 7) and Android 2.3.3(Nexus S). The result is the same in all.

Is there anything I am not doing right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you disabling the rotation in your androidmanifest.xml? check if you have something like configChanges for your activities.

Comment: No I do not have that `android:configChanges`

Comment: Then make sure that your folders are corresponding to the devices that you're using. I mean start with removing the hdpi, mdpi, etc... just make sure that layout-land is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way. Folders `layout` and `layout-land` should be on the same level.

You need `res/layout` and `res/layout-land`.

```
res
  |_ layout
  |_ layout-land
  |_ layout-...
  |_ layout-...
```

So, your setup should look like:

```
res
  |_ layout
          |_ activity_main.xml
  |_ layout-land-hdpi
          |_ activity_main.xml
  |_ layout-land-ldpi
          |_ activity_main.xml
  |_ layout-land-mdpi
          |_ activity_main.xml
  |_ layout-small-land-ldpi
          |_ activity_main.xml
```

Comment: This did it. Works now. It was so silly of me nesting it all inside layout/. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You must define all your layout-land folder into res folder instead of layout folder in this way :

`res/layout-land`

not like you did as

```
res/layout/layout-land
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your phone screen density is xhdpi for which you have not kept a folder. Also keep a folder for layout-land-xhdpi and try. you should also keep layout-land-xxhdpi.

Or you can just have layout-land